# Looking for a software to limit file count that a directory can contain?

Tags: file, count, directory, limit

I can not find such a software to limit a folder can hold x number of files in it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What operating system? I'm doubtful such software exists, but in Linux you may be able to get by with some hacky chmod-ing

Comment: In windows, I am suprised to not to be able to find one. It is a simple duty.

Comment: It is not trivial at all. This is a limit on the user that extends to the operating system level.

Comment: I do not mean that. I want to limit a folder containing x number of files. Let say if folder has 100 files, it would not allow 101th file.

Comment: This is not trivial at all. Folders are part of the underlying file system that is abstracted by the OS. Please specify in your question what operating system you are working with.